# Best way to render 3D animations in Swift from Maya

Tags: swift, 3d, maya, fbx, usdz

I've got two apps, one in Unity and one in iOS (created using Swift in Xcode). For the Unity game, our animator exports the 3D models from Maya into an `fbx` file which we are then able to render in the game.

Our challenge now is being able to render those same animations in the iOS game. I've read documentation that iOS supports `usdz` files. However, I'm having lots of trouble exporting the `fbx` files into `usdz`. These are the things I've tried:

1. I had our animator export the Maya file into Blender and then had them export to `usd`, which I then ran converted to `usdz` through Reality Converter. However, nothing shows up in the `SCNScene` (just a blank screen).
2. I downloaded all the appropriate SDKs from Apple and Autodesk to try and convert the the `fbx` file directly to `usdz` through Reality Converter, but when I run it in Swift, the textures seem to get messed up (we have a second layer of texture for eyes). Some `fbx` files turned out better than others. The below was the best one I could get.

[image: This one]

3. Lastly, I created a `.scn` file and dragged the different `dae`/`usdz` files into the scene which I'm able to see in the scene editor, but when I load the scene using `SCNScene(named: "filename")`, I get an empty scene (with a sky and ground though).
4. Worth mentioning, I've tried converting the animations to `dae` and `gtlf` files as well, but with no luck.

I've tried two permutations of code to load the animations into the scene:

directly into the scene:

```
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ferox", withExtension: "usdz") else { fatalError() }
        let scene = try! SCNScene(url: url, options: [.checkConsistency: true])
```

and also using an intermediary `MDLAsset`:

```
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ferox", withExtension: "usdz") else { fatalError() }
        let asset = MDLAsset(url: url)
        let scene = SCNScene(mdlAsset: asset)
```

There has to be a way to do this since fbx files are so common. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong (or even where, since there are so many different steps)?